# Convert from std::string to DWORD

Tags: c++, string, winapi, type-conversion, dword

I have a simple problem with a conversion:

```
std::string str = "0xC0A80A02"
```

and I need to convert it to DWORD.
I searched on the web and found some solution but none seems to work.
try1:

```
DWORD m_dwIP = atol(str.c_str());
```

try2:

```
std::istringstream ss(str.c_str());
ss >> m_dwIP;
```

try3:

```
sscanf (str.c_str(),"%u",str,&m_dwIP);
```

Note the string stores the value in hexa .

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: I tagged this as windows-api because it is windows specific (`DWORD` is not standard C++)

Comment: @mathepic thanks I'm a beginner with c++ and i get the types all mixed up

Comment: The question title sounds to me the same as "Convert banana into a pistol"... :-)

Comment: Yeah, what function are you passing this value to that takes type `DWORD`? Chances are, that library has some kind of hex converter function available, as well. Under normal circumstances, it's nonsensical to convert a string to a `DWORD`.

Comment: @Cody The library that I'm using is external and I dont have access to it. What I am trying to achieve is to add to a config file a value and then get that value at startup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`istringstream` will work fine, just strip off the `0x` prefix and use the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) formatter:

```
  std::string str = "0xC0A80A02";
  unsigned int m_dwIP;

  std::istringstream ss(&str[2]);
  ss >> std::hex >> m_dwIP;

  std::cout << std::hex << m_dwIP << "\n";
```

Outputs `c0a80a02`.

Comment: Or you can do what this answer says and have it done quicker.

Comment: DWORD is unsigned long, not int.

Comment: @Draco: `DWORD is `DWORD.  Declaring it as such will save you from surprises.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `sizeof(DWORD) == sizeof(unsigned long)`, this should do:

```
#include <cstdlib>
DWORD m_dwIP = std::strtoul(str.c_str(), NULL, 16);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/.

Note that this is usable for both C and C++ (strip of the `std::` and `c_str()` and change `<cstdlib>` to `<stdlib.h>` but this should be pretty obvious).

Comment: I've tested this implementation also and it works too. I wish i can select both answers.

Answer (score -3):

This is a fairly straightforward problem.  How would you, as a person, read that hexadecimal number and convert it to decimal?  If you are superhuman, you will just know it immediately, but if you are like the rest of us and use valuable brain space to remember non-computer things like how to swing a golf club, you'll have to do some arithmetic.  You'd use a mental algorithm to do the conversion, and what you need is code that does the thinking for you.  You can use this algorithm:

1. initialize an accumulator variable to 0
2. initialize a multiplier variable to 1
3. loop from the END of the string until you reach the beginning of the number (the 'x' char in your case)
4. for each char, take the hex value of the char (0-9 for 0-9, 10-15 for a-f) and multiply it by the multiplier, and add it to the accumulator
5. multiply your accumulator by 16 (or be cool and just shift to the left 4 bits)
6. repeat back to #3 until you finish all the digits

When you are all done, the value left in your accumulator is your result.

Comment: -1: This code does not need to be written as the standard library provides for it.  I wish I could down-vote a second time for the condescending tone.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't going for condescending with this one, I was trying to be excessively casual.  Good call on the standard implementation, though.